# encounter ERROR: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'StudentID' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql

need your help on this error, I need to insert the value of an array into a row in MySQL except the primary key which is set to auto increment. however  I encounter this error, below is my db structure and my code to insert:

```
     CREATE TABLE `predicted`  
(`StudentID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`Calc1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `ProgConcept` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `English1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `Physics1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `IntrotoIT` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483648 ;
```

and the code to insert was:

```
/**
 *
 * @author fobia
 */
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;

public class arraytodb {
    public static void sendtodb(String[]toarray, int lengthofarray){

        String db="";
        System.out.println("Length of array: "+lengthofarray);
        for(int i=0;i<toarray.length;i++){
            if(i==0){
            db="'"+toarray[i]+"'";

            }else{
            db=db+"'"+toarray[i]+"'";

            }

            System.out.println(">>"+toarray[i]+"\t");
        }
        int counter=1;
        for(int a=1;a<Integer.MAX_VALUE;a++){
            counter++;
        }
//==============================================================================

        try{
            Connection con = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thesis";
//  String db = "";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  Class.forName(driver);
  con =       (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
  try{
                java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
                //int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT dataset VALUES('019','"+db+")");
                int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO predicted (Calc1, ProgConcept, English1, Physics1, IntrotoIT) VALUES ('"+toarray[0]+"','"+toarray[1]+"' ,'"+toarray[2]+"', '"+toarray[3]+"', '"+toarray[4]+"')");
                System.out.println("1 row affected");
  }
  catch (SQLException s){
      s.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("failed");
  }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

}
```

the input for StudentID is has to be auto increment from one, and in this way I could not get it and always encounter error

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range
>   value for column 'StudentID' at row 1

thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if you run your insert query in MySQL directly? What id has the row?

Answer (score 1):

You must have to increase the size of the primary key value. On run time you are entering the value is not under the limitations of `INT(10)`.

You must increase the size of primary field that is **int** in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to insert an ID while creating. That is what the autoincrement column does for you ;)

Apart from that you are trying to insert a value that is larger than the maximum size of the column http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Answer (score 0):

You specify AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483648. Please remove this declaration, it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved by resetting the autoincrement value and insert per column value.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are creating a table with a predefined auto increment field, or you seem to have reached the max range for the auto increment field.

Use the following command to reset the auto increment value back to 1: 
ALTER TABLE predicted AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

While resetting, ensure that the existing data (if any) are backed up and the table truncated. Else a primary key violation will be generated as there could be existing data with the same key.